# Why do I want to use CRTP over simple template for static polymorphism?

Tags: c++, crtp

I have read a lot of posts about [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and I still do not see why I do not want to use it over just using template programming.

Below is an example slightly modified from Wikipedia:

```
template <class T> 
struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->implementation();
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation();
};
```

However, I can do exactly the same with just template in a more straightforward way:

```
template <class T> 
struct OuterClass
{
    void interface()
    {
        nested->implementation();
    }
private:
    T* nested;
};

struct NestedClass
{
    void implementation();
};

OuterClass<NestedClass> x;
x.interface();
```

What's the advantage of CRTP over my implementation?

Edit: the line `T* nested;` as member variable can also be just `T nested;` so that `nested` is created by the constructor of outer class.

Comment: The simplest answer I can think of is that in the latter case, the developers using this interface need to know how the types are combined -- they must explicitly say `OuterClass<NestedClass>`. In the CRTP case, particularly with private inheritance, this is a detail they don't have to be privy to. Side note: in the second example, `OuterClass<T>::nested` is uninitialized.

Comment: And what provides "T* nested"?

Comment: @Klaus It can always be provided by a default constructor

Comment: @cdhowie For the first point you made, I can just use typedef to get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I can do exactly the same

NO, you have an additional data member "T* nested" which is set during runtime. As this, the compiler has not the full knowledge of the exact object it will see and may optimize less optimal. In addition, you have an indirection via pointer which is not the case if you use "this", as the access to any data member is known at compile time, even if the author of a call has to write `static_cast<T*>(this)->something`, but the full operation is completely known at compile time.

What you do is more like a virtual function call than compile time polymorphism.

In addition you also have to set the nested pointer somewhere, which means something passed through the constructor, which is also overhead in code and speed.

And at last point I see, you need to create your object in two steps. First the "nested" one and than pass its pointer to the outer class. This can also result in performance drop and can have side effects like non contiguous memory, cache line misses and so on.

Comment: Wait... in the second case (unless `T::implementation()` is virtual) the compiler _does_ know the full operation at compile time. The only suboptimal thing I see here is the additional level of indirection to any of `*nested`'s data members. The method call is still dispatched the same way as in the CRTP approach.

Comment: @cdhowie "does know the full operation at compile time" No! If a call to a method did not need data member access, it can be made static. As this, it always is additional indirection!

Comment: There may be additional indirection to the data, but this makes it sound like the compiler can't even resolve the final function call until runtime, which is wrong. The compiler knows exactly which function will be called (again, assuming the function is non-virtual) it just doesn't know what `this` will be until runtime. It might still make plenty of optimizations, up to and including inlining the function call.

Comment: @cdhowie: It knows how to access the code, but not the data! And calling a method with accessing the data from the given object, which is not known at compile time results in less optimal optimization. Again: If you do not access data of your object in a method call, you make your method static. In this case, you do not need a pointer at all, but this has nothing to do with runtime or compile time polymorphism.

Comment: @Klaus I disagree. Instead of using pointer T*, I can just do it with a member variable as "T nested" which is created from default constructor of OuterClass. In that case everything is known at compile time.

Comment: @DiveIntoML: Also the default constructor must set the variable. That needs space and time. Why you ask if you did accept nothing which others present you? Every answer can have mistakes, but if there are no arguments to make the mistakes visible but an discussion starts, that a difference is no difference, than nothing can help. You need an additional var, you must initialise it, you must create objects step by step, fully independent if you do it before, in or after the construction, you can not optimize data access. OK, if you feel that is ok, use it, but it is different :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided is pretty much a home-brew of virtual functions-based polymorphism (assuming incomplete sample and having some code elsewhere which actually sets `T*`)

The main disadvantage of run-time polymorphism (aka type erasure) is performance. Since you need to dereference the pointer, compiler generally has no way of knowing at compile time which function is called, and thus can't inline the function and make decisions on side-effects of the function. On top of that, calling through pointer generally requires an extra step of pointer dereference, which also slows things down.